# Duplicate id within noscript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is the following HTML/Javascript valid (strict) when Javascript is enabled? Is the id in the noscipt tag ignored?

```
<body>
    <noscript>
        <div id="test"></div>
    </noscript>
    <script type="text/Javascript">
        var el = document.createElement('span');
        el.id = 'test';
        document.body.appendChild(el);
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When javascript is enabled, the content of `<noscript>` is [raw text](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tokenization.html#rawtext-state), not element content, so the child of the `<noscript>` element is a text node with value `"\n    <div id="test"></div>\n"` instead of a DIV element.  A `getElementById("test")` will not find a `<div>` with the ID `"test"` because there is no such element, only a text node whose content would parse to a DIV if it appeared outside a raw text context.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-noscript-element

> **Outside of head elements, if scripting is enabled for the `noscript` element**
>   The `noscript` element must contain only text...